# ReferenceError: window is not defined Angular Universal

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm using Angular 10 and trying to implement SSR in my project.

When I run the `npm run serve:ssr` I'm getting the below error

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

When I googled, they suggested to add `domino`

So below is my server.ts

```
....
const scripts = fs.readFileSync('dist/asfc-web/browser/index.html').toString();

const window = domino.createWindow(scripts);
global['window'] = window;
global['document'] = window.document;

....
```

still getting the same error, Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try identifying which of your dependencies is causing this

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's simple fix,

I've imported the `AppServerModule` after the `global['window']` and it worked

```
global['window'] = window;
global['document'] = window.document;

import { AppServerModule } from '../../projects/asfc-web/src/main.server';
```

Comment: Which version of angular did u test this ?

Comment: this doesnt work for me in latest version

Answer (score 0):

you can use Renderer2 listen for this.

```
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
```

```
 constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2) {
     ...
 }
```

```
this.renderer2.listen('window', 'load', event => {    
   this.innerWidth = event.currentTarget.innerWidth;
   console.log(this.innerWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

function _window(): any {
  return window;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WindowRef {
  get nativeWindow(): any {
    return _window();
  }
}
```

add in constructor where you want to use:

```
  constructor(
    private windowRef: WindowRef
  ) {
  }
```

and use like this:

```
  this.windowRef.nativeWindow.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
```

or you can check platform:

```
  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any,
    private windowRef: WindowRef
  ) {
  }
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
  this.windowRef.nativeWindow.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```